# How to set comments generator in English locale& in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, merge, resources, merge-conflict-resolution, smartgit

I want to merge resorces file, but user 1 has resources file with russian comments (his visual studio in english, but generates russian comments, like

```
/// <summary>
///   Ищет локализованную строку, похожую на ANPR camera images receiving error.
/// </summary>
```

but I need

```
/// <summary>
///   Looks up a localized string similar to ANPR camera images receiving error.
/// </summary>
```

And there are a lot of such points in resource file to merge in smart git.

What could be suggested to resolve my issue?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `International Settings`

Comment: we will merge tomorow, so I can try and answer this proposal in a one day...